# Не удается найти указанный файл. Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу

Tags: python

202290 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\ьлрдд\Desktop\afqks\dist\coderatpremium.exe.notanexecutable
202749 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 1 language 0
202761 INFO: Appending PKG archive to EXE
203374 INFO: Fixing EXE headers
223570 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
Не удается найти указанный файл.
Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . .

не понимаю в чем проблема, я чайник в програмировании. делал все по видосу с ютуба выдает такую ошибку в консоли в конце загрузки

Comment: А что вы собственно делаете, когда эта ошибка происходит - мы как-то догадаться должны?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/kamazz-fsociety/rat-via-telegram
особенно доставляет описание

а теперь цитата из рекламки:

> "Всем привет большое спасибо за 400 подписчиков, сегодня мы будем
> зарабатывать на Винлокере поехали!"

собственно сам файл: https://github.com/kamazz-fsociety/rat-via-telegram/blob/main/coderatpremium.py

Jesus Tortuga, вы поосторожней с желаниями!

Comment: Ого, либо товарищ модифицирует винлокер, либо сам на него попал. Однако

Comment: @CrazyElf, а вы что-то поняли из этого ответа? в вопросе, вроде бы, ничего из упомянутого в ответе не фигурирует. разве что кроме буквосочетания «rat».

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin coderatpremium тут общее, хотя возможно отвечавший ошибается, но выглядит подозрительно